# How do I use a variable in Excel VBA pivot table when using value filtering?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have the following sub:

```
Sub test()

DeviceModel = "123 Model_name"

        ActiveSheet.PivotTables(DeviceModel).PivotFields("Baseline Release").AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "Count of Device ID"

        ActiveSheet.PivotTables(DeviceModel).PivotFields("Baseline Release"). _
        PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueIsGreaterThan, DataField:=ActiveSheet. _
        PivotTables(DeviceModel).PivotFields("Count of Device ID"), Value1:=10

End Sub
```

This part works:

```
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables(DeviceModel).PivotFields("Baseline Release").AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "Count of Device ID"
```

But the second part doesn't:

```
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables(DeviceModel).PivotFields("Baseline Release"). _
        PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueIsGreaterThan, DataField:=ActiveSheet. _
        PivotTables(DeviceModel).PivotFields("Count of Device ID"), Value1:=10
```

If I replace (DeviceModel) with ("123 Model_name") it works as expected:

```
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("123 Model_name").PivotFields("Baseline Release"). _
        PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueIsGreaterThan, DataField:=ActiveSheet. _
        PivotTables("123 Model_name").PivotFields("Count of Device ID"), Value1:=10
```

It says: "application defined or object defined error"

I have done extensive googling and still cant figure out why it doesn't work with the variable instead of the actual table name.

Comment: Does a `with ActiveSheet.PivotTables(DeviceModel).PivotFields("Baseline Release")` have a similar result?

Comment: Yes, same result when using With

Comment: Perhaps excel is being a jerk about the variable not being declared first. Try adding `Dim DeviceModel As String` before you assign it a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in [Excel VBA - Pivot Table with Multiple Value Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242989/excel-vba-pivot-table-with-multiple-value-filters)

```
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Set pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(DeviceModel)

With pvt.PivotFields("Baseline Release")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueIsGreaterThan, DataField:=pvt.PivotFields("Count of Device ID"), Value1:=10
End With
```